# Unsubscribing from router events

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

I am struggling with the routing after being redirected to the previous site after logging in. e.g i call "localhost:4200/results" if i am not logged in i will be directed to the login with "localhost:4200?returnUrl=%2Fresults#login". The redirection works but if i want to navigate in the navbar to "localhost:4200/dashboard" it doesnt work. It shows "localhost:4200/dashboard" for 1 sec but doesnt route and the url still shows "localhost:4200/results". Tried with unsubscpription. Didnt work...

effects.ts

```
@Effect()
signInSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(AuthActions.signInSuccessAction),
map(action => {
  const authenticatedUser = action.user;
  if (authenticatedUser.competenceCenterMappings.length === 0) {
    return openModal({component: CreateCompetenceCenterComponent});
  } else  {
    const returnUrl = this.prevRouteService.redirectUrl;
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
    }).unsubscribe();
    return closeModal();
  }
})
);
```

auth-guard.ts

```
  canActivate(
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
return combineLatest([
  this.store.select(AuthenticationStore.Selectors.isAuthenticated),
  this.store.select(AuthenticationStore.Selectors.getUser)
]).pipe(
  mergeMap(
    ([isAuthenticated, authUser]) => isAuthenticated ? this.handleEnvironment(authUser) : this.router.navigate([], {
      fragment: 'login',
      queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }
    })
  )
);
```